# Get the rest of a string after spliting with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Given I have a string like this

```
done?id=http://api?auth=1335357
```

and I want to get only this

```
http://api?auth=1335357
```

I use this javascript code to do it :

```
var paramEmbed = myString.split('=')[1] + "=" + hashes[0].split('=')[2];
```

But as you can see this code is not really optimal because if there is another character "=" after the string I won't be able to get it. So is there a way to get all the following characters after the first "=" found ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
[yourstring].split(/={1}/).slice(1).join('=');
//e.g. for 'done?id=http://api?auth=1335357&foo=bar'
//=> http://api?auth=1335357&foo=bar
```

Answer (score 2):

suggestion from my head , simple solution.

```
'done?id=http://api?auth=1335357'.split('id=').pop();
```

so :

```
var paramEmbed =myString.split('id=').pop();
```

Comment: Well that is simple, I wonder why I haven't thought about it. Thanks.